# Pre packaged creme fraiche in quiche

Tags: quiche, creme-fraiche

I've seen creme fraiche recipes for quiche and I have some store bought creme fraiche on hand that was bought for me a few days ago.   My concern is that it's not real creme fraiche, it's half way towards butter - it's perfectly fine, but it tastes like it's closer to butter than real creme fraiche, which I imagine helps with the shelf-life.

A friend brought over a tiny tin of caviar and 8 oz of creme from the store (pre-packaged) so I have about 6 oz of the stuff and I don't know what to do with it.  It doesn't work on toast as butter, I tried it.  It's just wrong.

Will I ruin my quiche if I make it with this stuff?   Let me state that I'm not a low calorie quiche person, I use heavy cream and that's a proper decadent quiche in my opinion and if I have it once every 2-4 weeks, I don't worry about the calories.

The idea of a butter flavored quiche sounds kinda gross, so I'm leaning towards not doing it, or experimenting with just 1 egg and 4 oz of the creme - I think I'll try that.

Any advice is welcome on the store bought creme fraiche quiche idea or other things to do with the stuff that don't include more caviar, cause that's not in the budget.

I mean no ill will toward the product and I think Vermont Creamery is a good company, but I don't think this will make a good quiche and there's numerous creme fraice quiche recipes available.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid we cannot predict whether your quiche will taste gross to you or not. This is an entirely subjective thing. You can recognize it in your own question - to you, creme fraiche on toast tastes wrong, while it is a commonly enjoyed combination for many people.

Comment: @rumtscho but isn't that always true.  It's the Lox and Cream-cheese on cinnamon toast joke.   It doesn't work for most of us, but it might work for someone.   I also disagree with you on creme fraiche on toast.  Creme fraiche lends itself to sweet or savory - toast is neither but it can be a platform for that combination.  Creme Franchise can go on sweat muffins or pancakes or on toast with something else, like mushrooms.   Even if taste is individual, guidelines are somewhat universal.  A google search of creme fraiche on toast always mentioned a 3rd ingredient, never solo.

Comment: @rumtscho  I would add that you're making a mistake that a lot of moderators make on Stack Exchange.   Over-moderating.     I'm willing to bet that there are some people here who would have been interested in how the experiment worked out.   I'm not going to lose sleep over it, but I'm kind of surprised you would close this question.

Answer (score 3):

Creme Fraiche is more comparable to sour cream than it is to heavy cream, and it sounds like what you have is if anything even further from cream. You could certainly make a tasty quiche with it, but it would probably require the addition of additional liquid, and there's a chance it won't turn out well. If you're OK with risks and experimentation, go for it!
Otherwise, I'd suggest using it for something you'd usually use yogurt, sour cream, or cream cheese for.

Comment: I don't think extra liquid would be necessary... sour cream and (store-bought) creme fraiche both thin out pretty quickly as they warm.